# How to change pointCut expression inside an aspect which has been compiled when I use this aspect in other project?

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a logging aspect like this, it will print args, result or any other exceptions. I use aspectj-maven-plugin to compile this aspect. Then, the compiled result will be packaged to a jar. I will offer this jar to our maven repository, so they can depend this jar in their project. If they need log any request info, they just need write an annonation @Log at the method defination. I aslo want to offer "a package assign abilility": My colleage could set a package parameter when compile their project, then all the method invoke inside that package will be cut。

In summary, like the customPointCut in the following code, I want change the pointcut defination when I need this compiled asject in another project.

```
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {

    static private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(@com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.Log * *(..))")
    private void annoPointCut() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.project.package..*.*(..))")
    private void customPointCut() {}

    @Around("annoPointCut() || customPointCut()")
    public Object valid(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        } finally {
            log(xx,xx);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I could not find any parameterized aspect solution in aspect project or aspect-maven-plugin project

Comment: Like I already said in my [comment on your AspectJ Maven issue](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/issues/169#event-8896690040): Add an MCVE, i.e. a full, minimal sample project (ideally, some code directly in the question + a GitHub project to clone). Please also specify whether aspect library users use load-time weaving (LTW) or compile-time weaving (CTW) for incorporating the library aspects into their respective projects. My answer depends on this information. Do yourself a favour by giving your own question some more love and care. Then you will be better answers faster.

Comment: I am sorry, sir. [log-demo](https://github.com/chuanghou/log-demo),  There is a demo project in this respository. I have written question detail in the method comment. P.S. I use CTW

Comment: Well, thanks, but you did not share the link to the aspect project: https://github.com/chuanghou/milky. I had to search for it on GitHub, based on the dependency in your library consumer project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, annotation values must be compile-time constants, so you cannot change them. This is not an AspectJ issue, but a Java limitation.

So what you do in AspectJ is to define your logging aspect as **abstract** and the package pointcut also as abstract:

```java
@Aspect
public abstract class AutoLogAspect {
    // (...)

    @Pointcut("")
    public abstract void packagePC();

    // (...)
}
```

Then, in your demo project, you **override the abstract aspect, defining a concrete pointcut:**

```java
package com.example.log.demo;

import com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.AutoLogAspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyLogAspect extends AutoLogAspect {
    @Pointcut("within(com.example.log..*) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void packagePC() {}
}
```

Now, you can remove the `@Log` annotation from your sample class:

```java
package com.example.log.demo;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fool fool = new Fool();
        fool.testLogOfPackage("Hello World");
    }

    public static class Fool {
        public void testLogOfPackage(String str) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling with Maven, you willl see:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.14.0:compile (default) @ log-demo ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.example.log.demo.Main$Fool.testLogOfPackage(java.lang.String))' in Type 'com.example.log.demo.Main$Fool' (Main.java:10) advised by around advice from 'com.example.log.demo.MyLogAspect' (aspectj-tool-0.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar!AutoLogAspect.class(from AutoLogAspect.java))
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.example.log.demo.Main.main(java.lang.String[]))' in Type 'com.example.log.demo.Main' (Main.java:4) advised by around advice from 'com.example.log.demo.MyLogAspect' (aspectj-tool-0.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar!AutoLogAspect.class(from AutoLogAspect.java))
```

When running the sample program, the output will be:

```
Hello World

=====msg: execution(Main.Fool.testLogOfPackage(..))
==header: 09:12:00.329 [main-INFO ] com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.AutoLogAspect:386 : [success:true] [cost:0] [result:]
===milky: [class:com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.AutoLogAspect] [method:log] [line:66]
====args: [arg0:Hello World] [arg1:] [arg2:] [arg3:] [arg4:] [arg5:]

=====msg: execution(Main.main(..))
==header: 09:12:00.334 [main-INFO ] com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.AutoLogAspect:386 : [success:true] [cost:7] [result:]
===milky: [class:com.stellariver.milky.aspectj.tool.log.AutoLogAspect] [method:log] [line:66]
====args: [arg0:[Ljava.lang.String;@4ff4357f] [arg1:] [arg2:] [arg3:] [arg4:] [arg5:]
```

See? There is no need to copy & paste the whole aspect. You simply make the package pointcut abstract and force consuming projects to override it. Clean and simple.

P.S.: If the consuming project would use load-time weaving instead of compile-time weaving, you could define the overriding aspect in *aop.xml* directly, no need to compile a source aspect or use AspectJ Maven Plugin at all in the consuming project. But CTW or LTW, both works nicely, the rest is up to you.

Comment: Thanks so much! This question has haunted me for a very long time!

Comment: That's what I want, clean and simply

Comment: Hi,   could you answer this questions? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889724/aspecj-maven-plugin-weaving-dependency-feature-random-load-java-class